# Read All Sibling Node Elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have a situation where I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<initialize>
 <boxes>
  <box>
     <compliment>RayTest1</compliment>
     <description>RayTest1</description>
     <boxtype>RayTest</boxtype>
     <il>1.00</il>
     <ib>1.00</ib>
     <ih>1.00</ih>
     <ol>1.00</ol>
     <ob>1.00</ob>
     <oh>1.00</oh>
     <bw>1.00</bw>
     <bgw>1.00</bgw>
     <boxstrength>1</boxstrength>
  </box>
  <box>
     <compliment>RayTest2</compliment>
     <description>RayTest2</description>
     <boxtype>RayTest</boxtype>
     <il>99.99</il>
     <ib>99.99</ib>
     <ih>99.99</ih>
     <ol>99.99</ol>
     <ob>99.99</ob>
     <oh>99.99</oh>
     <bw>99.99</bw>
     <bgw>99.99</bgw>
     <boxstrength>99</boxstrength>
  </box>
 </boxes>
</initialize>
```

What I need to accomplish in C# is this:

A user is going to upload an xml file to my page.

I need to parse through each box of the xml file, assign the values to an object, and then add that object to a list for display in an ASP.NET MVC App.

I've attempted to do this in the following way:

```
                try
                {
                    List<BoxViewModel> boxesList = new List<BoxViewModel>();
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load(fileFromPage.FileName);

                    XmlNodeList boxNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//initialize/boxes").ChildNodes;

                    foreach (XmlNode boxNode in boxNodeList)
                    {
                        XmlNode currentBoxNode = boxNode;
                        BoxViewModel currentBox = new BoxViewModel();

                        currentBox.Compliment = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//compliment").InnerText;
                        currentBox.Description = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//description").InnerText;
                        currentBox.BoxType = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//boxtype").InnerText;
                        currentBox.InsideLength = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//il").InnerText);
                        currentBox.InsideBreadth = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//ib").InnerText);
                        currentBox.InsideHeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//ih").InnerText);
                        currentBox.OutsideLength = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//ol").InnerText);
                        currentBox.OutsideBreadth = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//ob").InnerText);
                        currentBox.OutsideHeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//oh").InnerText);
                        currentBox.BoxWeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//bw").InnerText);
                        currentBox.BoxGrossWeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//bgw").InnerText);
                        currentBox.BoxStrength = int.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("//boxstrength").InnerText);

                        boxesList.Add(currentBox);
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    ViewBag.MsgText = "There was an error when processing the file!";
                    ViewBag.MsgColor = "Red";
                }
```

The problem I am experiencing here is that when I do it this way, every box is the same. It only gets the first box. The foreach loop is smart enough to know that there are two boxes, but it can't get the second box and add it to my list. Instead, I have a list of two of the same box.

I am willing to change almost anything about this to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `System.Xml` really likes to "eat" more than it should. I recommend using LINQ to XML instead.

Comment: So if I had 100 or 1000 boxes, would I even get a page back? Or would it time out in MVC you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the root of the XML document, that's why only the data from the first element is being read. Get rid of the `//` in your call to `SelectSingleNode`:

```
            currentBox.Compliment = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("compliment").InnerText;
            currentBox.Description = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("description").InnerText;
            currentBox.BoxType = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("boxtype").InnerText;
            currentBox.InsideLength = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("il").InnerText);
            currentBox.InsideBreadth = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ib").InnerText);
            currentBox.InsideHeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ih").InnerText);
            currentBox.OutsideLength = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ol").InnerText);
            currentBox.OutsideBreadth = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ob").InnerText);
            currentBox.OutsideHeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("oh").InnerText);
            currentBox.BoxWeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("bw").InnerText);
            currentBox.BoxGrossWeight = decimal.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("bgw").InnerText);
            currentBox.BoxStrength = int.Parse(currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("boxstrength").InnerText);
```

You can also use ./ to indicate current context:

```
currentBox.Compliment = currentBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("./compliment").InnerText;
...
```

Comment: Yes! That worked! Is there a site I can learn how to properly use Xml-related classes?

Comment: I used this to learn XPath syntax.  It's pretty good, with lots of examples.

http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Comment: [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlDocument(v=vs.110).aspx) for `XmlDocument` has code examples. The issue you were having is actually XPath syntax. You can take a look at [W3Schools XML and XPath page](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_xpath.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
XmlNodeList boxNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//initialize/boxes").ChildNodes;
```

try using:

```
XmlNodeList boxNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/initialize/boxes/box");
```

That should get you a node list of each box node.

Comment: Yeah, I applied that just now. My code looks a lot cleaner now.